# styling layout of facebook facepile iframe

Tags: css, facebook

I was wondering if it is possible to style the layout of facebooks facepile iframe? Ideally I would like to float the profile pics to the right instead of having them below the '1 friend uses *_*' text? Can any control be given to this or is it what you see it what you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css will not work from outside the iframe

It's for security reasons. The domain of the iframe src is not the same as the domain of your page. So it is forbidden to have access to the iframe content from outside, e.g. per CSS or per JavaScript

So it's WYSIAYG (What you see is ALL you get)

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible, read here: http://miklasnjor.com/en/2011/css-style-facebook-fanbox-fanpage-facepile-pagestream/